# How to set project properties globally in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to disable "Compile on Save" option in project, properties, build->compiling in netbeans. How can I globally do it without having to individually set each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good question, but unfortunately I don't think it is possible, so this is an answer without a solution.

If there was a global setting it would presumably be on the **Tools > Options > Editor > On Save > Language > Java** screen, but it isn't there:

[image: On Save screen]

I don't see anything for this on the screens for the individual build tools either: **Tools > Options > Java**, then **Ant** or **Gradle** or **Maven**.

You might consider raising this as a new feature request for NetBeans through [Apache's Jira web site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-6298?filter=allopenissues). They may or may not implement your proposal, but they will certainly let you know if that functionality already exists.